# Roundcube login via PHP script

Tags: php, authentication, webmail

For a long time there was a php script [here](http://blog.philippheckel.com/2008/05/16/roundcube-login-via-php-script/) in order to perform automatic login to [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/), i.e. you specify username and password in the script and in case of success you can open roundcube interface without going through the process of authentication.

This script is good for those who have a system where user enters with his username and password at the beginning of the session and afterwards he can access his webmail client without going through the authentication process of webmail client.

But, this script stopped working for a new version of Roundcube which is v.0.6. Does anybody know how to make this script to work with 0.6 version also? Or any other suggestions will be appreciated also.

Thank you,

Bak

Answer (score 1):

The [Philip C. Heckel](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2008/05/16/roundcube-login-via-php-script/)'s script you have mentionned seems to work perfectly and was tested until version 0.9.2 of Roundcube.
[Reading comments](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2008/05/16/roundcube-login-via-php-script/#comment-147146) tells there's people who have done it working with versions 1.2+ .

There is also the [Alexjeen's alternative](https://github.com/alexjeen/Roundcube-AutoLogin) based on [the original Philip C. Heckel's script](https://blog.heckel.xyz/uploads/2008/05/RoundcubeLogin.class.phps) that seems to work with newer 1.0.2+ version. (Not tested)

Comment: Just to confirm that Alexjeen's alternative (https://github.com/alexjeen/Roundcube-AutoLogin) working for Roundcube Webmail 1.1.4